# When does Dash release memory?

Tags: python, openshift, plotly-dash

I wrote a python Dash app and made it available within my organization using OpenShift. I’m not really knowledgeable about OpenShift but it seems to be running correctly, including when multiple users are involved.

My problem is with memory management. **Each time a user initiates a new session, the memory used by Dash app increases by ~200MB when I look on OpenShift. When the user closes the browser tab, the consumed memory does not go down (not even after weeks)**. Essentially the amount of memory the Dash app consumes keeps growing.

I am probably missing something, but how do I get Dash to clear memory after the user closes the browser tab or after some time passes since the last action? The dcc.Store objects in my code have "storage_type = ‘memory’ ". But from what I understand the dcc.Store keeps all the stored data on the client side in the browser, so this should not increase the memory on the server.

I deployed my app with

```
app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=False, port=8080, host=“0.0.0.0”)
```

in case this matters.

Any help would be really appreciated! Right now I keep manually restarting the app to clear the memory but this is not practical at all. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Does the memory eventually go down after a user ends their session? I would guess either some caching is occurring, the session isn't terminating on the remote side, or a memory leak exists.

Comment: The memory never seems to go down. This cannot be my dcc.Store() objects right? That should be memory in the client browser, not on the server?

Also, when/how does Dash realize that the user terminated the session? If the user closes the tab? Should the ending of the session trigger some kind of cleanup function to remove any memory associated with it?

Comment: The error is most likely related to your implementation. Please post a MWE (code) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I wrote this code for my company and I would have to share proprietary input data in order to let you test it. It is also a few thousand lines long, so it is hard to pinpoint the source of this problem and therefore hard to make a MWE. Is there any obvious thing I could check here in order to track this problem down? I am just using standard callbacks I think. Alternatively, could I alter the Python script in a way so that it reboots every week to clear the memory?

Comment: was this ever figured out?

Answer (score 0):

How much memory are you allocating to the container? Also, does the memory continually go up? Or once it reaches a certain level does it plateau? Are you tracking any GC behavior in Python?

I'm not an expert on Python memory management, and know nothing about Dash, but Python does manage its own memory heap and has a garbage collector. Thus it is completely normal behavior for Python to never deallocate memory, Python is essentially reserving the memory for potential future use. Once it needs memory it will garbage collect the unreferenced objects.

As long as you aren't running out of memory or seeing undesirable GC behavior, the best thing to do is just set reasonable memory requests/limits for the container and let the Python GC manage the memory it has been allocated.

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue with dash on one of our company legacy apps. Unfortunately, I cannot share the code.

I tried to use `gc.collect()` after each callback, it is not recommended to do and it didn't help.

My problem was that the script didn't properly initialize Dash.
I added the following at the start of the script:

```
app=dash.Dash(__name__)
server=app.server
```

This kind of solved memory issue problems.

`app.run_server` should be used for development environment (there should be a warning when you run it). In case of prod, you need to use something like `gunicorn`. It has a learning curve, but it is not a steep one. If you insist on using `app.run_server`, you should set `debug=False` it will reduce memory consumption and increase speed.